# why does Hadoop RM show 0 for Memory Total and VCores Total?

Tags: hadoop

I have installed a pseudo-distributed Hadoop according to [the Hadoop website](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html).
When I run wordcount example and it get stuck in runing INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job. So, I checked the RM GUI, it shows Memory Total and VCores Total as 0.

[image: Hadoop RM image]

The settings I have are the same as Hadoop website.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly post logs if you are facing issue after this.You can try the changing the properties in below files

**Mapred-site.xml**

- `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb = 4000`
- `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts = -Xmx3768m`
- `mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores = 2`
- `mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores = 2`

(If you have installed Yarn) **yarn-site.xml**

- `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname = hostname_of_the_master`
- `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 4000`
- `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 2`
- `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 4000`

Answer (score 0):

from the screeshot it's clear that your nodemanager node has some problem(unhealthy). please check the nodemanager log to identify the cause and fix  it. after that only you can see the available cores and ram as expected.